# Why does a Twitter API request for a user's timeline with count=40 return about half the number of results that it should?

Tags: twitter

Why does

`http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=erikvold&page=0&count=40`

return approximately 15 results?

Should it not return 40 results?

Comment: APIs are a concern of developers, not web app users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading the documentation for the new API on `api.twitter.com` and using the old API, `twitter.com`, and the old API didn't include the `include_rts` parameter because retweets didn't exist back then.

The old API is basically useless now. I just had to use `api.twitter.com` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer is being added nearly 3 years later, mainly for the benefit of new API 1.1 users arriving via Google.)

As well as the answers you've already had, the `count` parameter is a maximum limit, not a "please send me `count` many".

The `count` parameter is best described in the documentation for [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline):

> The value of `count` is best thought of as a limit to the number of tweets to return because suspended or deleted content is removed after the count has been applied. We include retweets in the count, even if `include_rts` is not supplied. It is recommended you always send `include_rts=1` when using this API method.

Whilst some of that documentation is only relevant to the specific method, `count` appears to behave in that manner across the Twitter API — it won't reliably given you as many as `count` results from your method call, but it *will* reliably give you *no more than* `count` results.

Answer (score 0):

Retweets are not included by default.

> This method will not include retweets in the XML and JSON responses unless the include_rts parameter is set. The RSS and Atom responses will always include retweets as statuses prefixed with RT.

[Source](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline)